# VUE Update composable data in another composable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component calling a method to retrieve some data, let's call it methodA, this methodA is defined in a composable (composableA).
I have another composable (composableB) with a variable varB who is reactive (ref).
I want to be able to update varB at the end of methodA.

Any idea how I can do it ?
At the moment varB is not updated when I'm setting it using a setter.
Even while using a computed for varB it seems the computed does not detect any changes.

What I currently have.

```
import {setVarB} from "./composableB";
export const useComposableA = () => {
    const {setVarB} = useComposableB();
    const methodA = () => {
        axios.get().then(res => setVarB(res.data));
    }

    return {
        methodA
    }

}

export const useComposableB = () => {
    const varB = ref(null);
    const setVarB = (data) => {
        varB.value = data
    }
    return {
        setVarB
    }
}

<script setup>
import {onMounted} from "vue";
import {useComposableA} from "../composableA";

const {methodA} = useComposableA();
onMounted(() => {
    methodA();
})
</script>
```

Update :
Here is a link to some code to have a better visualization of the problem [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sharp-wozniak-kv2qhz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your linked code example, it is normal that the value of varB is not updated. Vue composable create new refs whenever they are called, so the varB from useComposableA is different from the one in your component.

There is more information [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) about this as well as shared state.

Another option is to use a state management library like pinia.

**Answer before edit :**

A few things here ! First, you are not calling methodA here so there is no way for you to call setVarB. Second, you are not returning anything from useComposableB, so this line `const { setVarB } = useComposableB()` should give you an error.

Modify useComposableB like so :

```js
export const useComposableB = () => {
    const varB = ref(null);
    const setVarB = (data) => {
        varB.value = data
    }

    return { varB, setVarB }
}
```

and your component like so :

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

 const {methodA} = useComposableA();

onMounted(() => {
  methodA()
})
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, even thought I read multiple times to make sure I did not make any mistaked it seems I did, my bad, I updated the question and I linked a code example to better visualize the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Yes thank you,
Thanks to your response I did get the "will create its own copies" thing.

For anyone reading this later,
You CAN share the state by importing (in this example) varB in the composableA so that you have an instance of composableB in composableA and then exporting varB in composableA to use it in the vue component. But it is really ugly and you do not know if anyone who will use composableA or composableB after you will understand that composableB needs to be used only in composableA.

So yea, the solution would be to create a store with moduleA and moduleB (if using vuex)